# Cannot cast from Vector<Object> to Integer

Tags: java, database, jsp, javabeans

I am trying to display all results from a  database but i get the following errors on the results loop: 
Cannot cast from Vector to Integer
Cannot cast from Vector to String

```
<% 
    Vector<Object> Results = scoreBean.getAllResults();
    String homeTeam;
    String awayTeam;
    int homeScore;
    int awayScore;
    final int NUM_FIELDS = 4;



for (int i=0;i<Results.size()/NUM_FIELDS;i++) 
{
 homeTeam = (String)Results.elementAt(i*NUM_FIELDS); \\\error here
            awayTeam = (String)Results.elementAt(i*NUM_FIELDS + 1); \\\error here
            homeScore = (Integer)Results.elementAt(i*NUM_FIELDS + 2);\\\error here
            awayScore = (Integer)Results.elementAt(i*NUM_FIELDS + 3);\\\error here

    %>  
    <TR>
        <TD><%= homeTeam %></TD>
        <TD><%= awayTeam %></TD>
        <TD><%= homeScore %></TD>
        <TD><%= awayScore %></TD>
    </TR>
    <%
         }
```

Comment: What do you mean you "cannot" do it? Compiler error? What does it say? Something else?

Comment: You should use collections..

Comment: The exception just tells that your `Vector` contains another `Vector`s and not `Integer`s or `String`s. Showing the code behind `getAllResults()` should give the answerers clues. In the meanwhile, learn how to create and use *real* javabeans. In spite of the fact that you're nowhere using javabeans, you've placed the `[javabeans]` tag on the question. Put your mouse on top of the `[javabeans]` tag until a black box shows up and then click therein the *info* link.

Answer (score 1):

From the error, it is likely that the values stored in the `Vector` are not actually integers:

```
homeScore = (Integer)Results.elementAt(i*NUM_FIELDS + 2);\\\error here
awayScore = (Integer)Results.elementAt(i*NUM_FIELDS + 3);\\\error here
```

hence the `ClassCastException`. Check the types of the values that are stored in the collection.

Some notes:

- `Vector` collections are obsolete. Use an `ArrayList` instead.
- Also using scriptlets is a bad idea, consider using [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jstl) `forEach` for iterating through the collection.